# Hat matrix: various results in linear algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, transpose

In the question, the hat matrix $H = I-x(x^Tx)^{-1}x^T$ is an $n$ x $n$ matrix. $x$ is a $n$ x $p$ vector, whose columns are linearly dependent. How do I show that $Hx = 0$, $H^T = H$, and $H^2 = H$. I'm a bit confused as when I try and manipulate $H$, I get $x(x^Tx)^{-1}x^T = xx^{-1}(x^T)^{-1}x^T = I$ which would imply $H = 0$? This obviously doesn't make sense. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Since $x$ is not square, the expression $x^{-1}$ does not make sense (rectangular matrices do not have inverses in the usual sense, they may have right/left inverses but they are not unique). But $x^T x$ is a $p \times p$ matrix which (I guess is assumed to be) invertible, so $(x^T x)^{-1}$ does make sense, but cannot be split into simpler parts.

Comment: Ah, of course! I didn't take care with the dimensions of the matrices. Thank you!

Comment: So, have you tried to show any of the things?

Comment: Yes, I've got the results now! I do have another question though: Show that if $v$, which is a $n$ x $1$ vector, is orthogonal to every column vector of $x$, then $Hv=v$. ($x$ is a fixed matrix). I haven't done much linear algebra work recently, so I feel like I'm missing something basic here that I can't remember. Thanks!

Comment: The rows of $x^Tv$ are the dot products of $v$ with $x$'s columns, because of how matrix multiplication works.

Comment: Ah, I see. So $Hv = v - x(x^Tx)^{-1}x^Tv = v- x(x^Tx)^{-1}0 = v$?

Comment: Also, how would I find the eigenvalues of H?

Comment: You know $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$ and all vectors perpendicular to $x$ are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$. So, you already possess the answer. (I was not alerted to your comments because you didn't write @runway44. You get alerted to comments because you're the OP.)